# Salesforce Authorization with Sandbox

Tags: oauth-2.0, salesforce, integration, salesforce-service-cloud

Our app has a Salesforce integration, so our clients can authorize through our Salesforce App and sync their data. One of our clients wants to use Sandbox, do I need to create a separate app for that or I can just use the existing app with sandbox url? Do I need different Salesforce api keys?

If yes, how can I create a Salesforce Sandbox account so users can auth thought it?

Answer (score 0):

if your application is currently connected to the production and then you have to create a new connected app in the sandbox and from there you and after creating a connected app in the sandbox you will find new consumer key and secret key which will be used for connecting the app to salesforce.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create another user account with special profile to limit the client that the permission.

Because the Salesforce have the limit (according your license or env ) to create sandbox env . So i suggest that you create another user account into the same sandbox.